# Flask - get() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, json, flask

I have these methods:

```
def hardCoded(rng):
    numbers_to_add = list(range(rng))
    try:
        req = request.Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/total'
            , data=bytes(json.dumps(numbers_to_add), 'utf_8')
            , headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            , method='POST')
        result = json.loads(request.urlopen(req).read(), encoding='utf_8')
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

class rangeNumbers(Resource):
    def get(self, rng):
        rng_num = rangeNumbers()
        rng_num.get(10000001)
        return {'data': directSum.hardCoded(rng).get(10000001)}

api.add_resource(rangeNumbers, '/range/<range>')
```

On visiting url `/range/<range>` , it should give me the result of that range `10000001`

However when I try `http://localhost:5000/range/range` it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/test_sum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'range'
```

Maybe I should use `/range/<10000001>` as a url query for this?

It should show something like this as a result:

```
`{
    "total": 50000005000000
}
```

`
Thanks

Comment: You are passing a keyword arg `range` to a function expecting `rng`

Comment: Can You elaborate please? I certainly understand what You mean, but this is about a number range, but I rather not use 'range' as a keyword name

Comment: Flask passes the url route variables as keywords to the function. See [Flask Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#url-route-registrations). So when you defined a path with `'/range/<range>'` your function is going to be called with `(self, range = somValue)`. Maybe you can alter the default behavior of Flask, but I didn't see anything in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the parameter rng of get(self, rng) function should be the "range". I met the problem as you, then change the function parameter name to the value between Angle brackets （<>）. You can try.